# CSS: position fixed для заголовка таблицы - выровнять height ячеек

Tags: jquery, css3

Хочу зафиксировать заголовок html-таблицы при прокрутке, чтобы он все время был на виду и юзера. Пытаюсь делать это с помощью js-скрипта, найденного на просторах сети.

Но я не могу решить проблему с выравниванием высоты всех th. Они выравниваются по содержанию. 
И получается то, что на скриншоте. Высота ячеек в строке разная (я специально цветом ее выделила для наглядности).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выровнять высоту всех th?
Банальные вещи типа height: auto; или height: 100%; не помогли.

Что-то тут нужно другое написать:

```
'height': $(th).outerHeight(true) + 'px'
```

Подскажите, что именно?
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой html:

```
    <table id="table-flats" class="fixtable">
 <tr>

 <th><span><a name="flats"></a><code class="html"><br />Кол-во<br /> комнат</code></span></th>
 <th data-th=", Характеристики"><code>Р-н</code></th>
 <th><code class="html"> Адрес</code></th>
 <th><code class="html">Метро</code></th>
 <th><code class="html">Эт</code></th>
 <th><code class="html">S <br /><br />о<br />б<br />щ</code></th>
 <th><code class="html">S <br /><br />к<br />о<br />м<br />н</code></th>
 <th><code class="html">S<br /><br />к<br />у<br />х</code></th>
 <th><code class="html">Т<br />е<br />л</code></th>
  <th><code class="html">М<br />е<br />б</code></th>
 <th><code class="html">Х<br />о<br />л</code></th>
  <th><code class="html">С<br />т<br />М<br />&nbsp;</code></th>
 <th><code class="html"><strong>Цена</strong></code></th>
 <th><code class="html">Срок</code></th>
 <th><code class="html">Примечания</code></th>
 </tr>
```

css:

```
.fixtable-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color: #FCF8E4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

И вот скрипт js, переопределяющий стили при прокрутке:

```
function FixTable(table) {
    var inst = this;
    this.table  = table;

    $('tr > th',$(this.table)).each(function(index) {
        var div_fixed = $('<div/>').addClass('fixtable-fixed');
        var div_relat = $('<div/>').addClass('fixtable-relative');
        div_fixed.html($(this).html());
        div_relat.html($(this).html());
        $(this).html('').append(div_fixed).append(div_relat);
        $(div_fixed).hide();
    });

    this.StyleColumns();
    this.FixColumns();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        inst.FixColumns()
    }).resize(function(){
        inst.StyleColumns()
    });
}

FixTable.prototype.StyleColumns = function() {
    var inst = this;
    $('tr > th', $(this.table)).each(function(){
        var div_relat = $('div.fixtable-relative', $(this));
        var th = $(div_relat).parent('th');
        $('div.fixtable-fixed', $(this)).css({
            'width': $(th).outerWidth(true) - parseInt($(th).css('border-left-width')) + 'px',
            'height': $(th).outerHeight(true) + 'px',
            'left': $(div_relat).offset().left - parseInt($(th).css('padding-left')) + 'px',
            'padding-top': $(div_relat).offset().top - $(inst.table).offset().top + 'px',
            'padding-left': $(th).css('padding-left'),
            'padding-right': $(th).css('padding-right')
        });
    });
}

FixTable.prototype.FixColumns = function() {
    var inst = this;
    var show = false;
    var s_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var h_top = $(inst.table).offset().top;

    if (s_top < (h_top + $(inst.table).height() - $(inst.table).find('.fixtable-fixed').outerHeight()) && s_top > h_top) {
        show = true;
    }

    $('tr > th > div.fixtable-fixed', $(this.table)).each(function(){
        show ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide()
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fixtable').each(function() {
        new FixTable(this);
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `position: sticky;` 

но у него поддержка так себе → https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

```css
table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Ненужное демо */
table { counter-reset: num; }
.num { counter-increment: num; }
.num td { border: 1px solid #123; }
.num td::after { content: counter(num); }
body { height: 1500px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><span><a name="flats"></a><code class="html"><br>Кол-во<br>комнат</code></span></th>
    <th data-th=", Характеристики"><code>Р-н</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">Адрес</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">Метро</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">Эт</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">S <br><br>о<br>б<br>щ</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">S <br><br>к<br>о<br>м<br>н</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">S<br><br>к<br>у<br>х</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">Т<br>е<br>л</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">М<br>е<br>б</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">Х<br>о<br>л</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">С<br>т<br>М<br>&nbsp;</code></th>
    <th><code class="html"><strong>Цена</strong></code></th>
    <th><code class="html">Срок</code></th>
    <th><code class="html">Примечания</code></th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr class="num"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если уж влезли в скрипты, то проще:
а) выкинуть позиционирование нафиг.
б) на онскролл таблицы навесить изменение стиля для `tr`-ки хедера, а конкретно свойства `transform:translateY(...)`.

Как-то в эту сторону:

HTML:

```
<div onscroll="forceScroll(this.id);">
    <table>
        <tr id="tHeader"> ...</tr>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function forceScroll(what) {
    var  shift = document.getElementById(what).scrollTop;
    document.getElementById('tHeader').style.transform = 'translateY(' + shift + 'px';            
}
```